# How to send apprequest by Spring Social Facebook

Tags: java, facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I have been digging Spring Social (1.0.2.RELEASE) for Facebook. I couldn't find out how to send apprequest via spring social. I already have an application on facebook with keys and stuff. I can fetch friends etc. but cannot send apprequest to a particular facebook user. Would really appreciate.

Comment: How you fetched friends data via spring-social-facebook?

Comment: What problems did you encounter? the documentation ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/ ) is pretty good for this, the JS SDK triggers the requests dialog and you need some server side code for accepting and deleting the requests

Comment: Spring social abstracts the details, for instance the code for getting friend profiles is `List<FacebookProfile> friendProfiles = facebook.friendOperations().getFriendProfiles();`. There must be something like `facebook.???Operations.send???(userId,redirect,data,message);` So there is nothing to do with the documentation on developers.facebook.com since spring handles it for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example should do the trick - i.e. create an app access token and then create the request using a FacebookTemplate which has been initialised using the created app access token

```
// retrieve app access token
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app_secret>",  String.class);
String appAccessToken = result.replaceAll("access_token=", "");

// create the request       
FacebookTemplate appRequestTemplate = new FacebookTemplate(appAccessToken);
String userId = "1234567890";
MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
requestData.set("message", "Sending a request through to you...");
String resultOfApprequest = appRequestTemplate.publish(userId, "apprequests", requestData);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook docs, app requests are sent to users by POSTs to the Graph API. See the "Create" section here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests

Spring Social Facebook has a GraphApi class with two methods for sending POSTs, "publish()" which tries to extract an id from the response and "post()" which doesn't:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/GraphApi.html

So you may need to make a call along the lines of:

```
Map<String, Object> requestData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
requestData.put("message", "My app's request message");
String requestId = graphApi.publish(userId, "apprequests", requestData);
```

Comment: Note that the endpoint requires an app access token, not a user access token. Typically, FacebookTemplate is constructed with a user access token (especially when constructed via the connection framework) and so that endpoint won't work. However, you should still be able to manually construct a FacebookTemplate with an app access token (obtained via client credentials grant) and post to that endpoint. It's a bit kludgy, but should work. I should really consider proper handly of app-level requests like this in FacebookTemplate so this is less kludgy. Consider this noted.